# Extracting title and the paragraph from website with BS4 ,request

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
def main(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"}
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    article_title = soup.find('h1',class_='entry-title')
    print(article_title.text)
    content=soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'td-post-content'})
    #print(content)
if __name__=='__main__':
    url = "https://shorturl.at/fgLU8"
    main(url)
```

**Error **

```
    print(article_title.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Can you please explain what is the issue for fetching data from the website,AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' coming multiple time when i need title as a text formate
URL in short formate paste in browserso get many URL

Comment: What is the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal is to get the text inside the `h1` with a class of `entry-title`
if that is your goal this would do the job

```
data =  requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
article = soup.find('div',class_='td-post-content tagdiv-type')
entry_title = soup.find('h1',class_='entry-title').text()
print(entry_title)
```

but a better solution would be like this

```
data =  requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
entry_title_s = "#copy and past Element Selector here"
entry_title = soup.select(entry_title_s)[0].text.strip() if page.select(entry_title_s) else 'N/A'
print(entry_title)
```

if you provide more information about your code or the website you are trying to scrap maybe I can be more specific

[Here is how to get the CSS selector](https://www.scrapingbee.com/tutorials/how-to-extract-css-selectors-using-chrome/)

Comment: I edit the code now you can check on it